# Can we use vault with kubernetes without sidecar or init container?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Our current model is to use init containers to fetch secrets from vault. But When the application crashes due to OOM issues, the pod goes into crashloopback state. Also, we don't want to overload the pod with a sidecar container. Is there any other way to use vault with kubernetes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Vault without using the side-car container.

You can create a path into the vault and save the key-value pair inside it.

As per requirement use the **KV1** and **KV2**

To sync vault values with Kubernetes secret you can use :
https://github.com/DaspawnW/vault-crd

**Vault CRD** is the custom resource that will sync your vault variables to Kubernetes secret on the specific intervals you define.

Each time new value updated in vault that will sync back to secret and you can inject that secret into deployment or statefulset as per need